# Set the class of all Input Boxes in Yii2

Tags: css, class, yii2, form-control

I have a web application designed in Yii2. The client wants all the text boxes to be shorter/smaller. In bootstrap, in addition to "form-control", I'd need to add the "input-sm" class as well.

However, as far as Yii2 is concerned, the form-control class is set in the model. Example: ActiveField model's has

```
'inputOptions' => [
    'class' => 'form-control',
],
```

However, I am using various widgets and extensions and need a supported solution to set the class such that with a few edits, I can make all text boxes and other controls look smaller. I don't want to mention a custom inputOptions in every form.

One solution could be to extend all the models I use and setting the class (input-sm) there, but would prefer a CSS or simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend Your Active Field Class as:-

```
<?php


namespace auction\widgets;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

class ActiveField extends \yii\widgets\ActiveField{

    //Error Options For Active Field Error Tag
    public $errorOptions= ['class' => 'error', 'tag' => 'span'];

    public function init(){

        //Changing Input Options Merge with form-class
        $this->inputOptions = ['placeHolder' => $this->model->getAttributeLabel($this->attribute), 'class' => 'input-sm'];

        parent::init();
    }

    /**
     * @param null $label Setting Label Value to false
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function label($label = null, $options = [])
    {

        $this->parts['{label}'] = '';

    }

}
```

now use ActiveForm As:-

```
      <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => 'login-form',
                    'fieldClass' => 'auction\widgets\ActiveField',
                    'successCssClass' => false,
                    'options'=> ['role' => 'form']]); ?>
```

Comment: Yep, as mentioned I could extend the active field class, but I need to make the other boxes used in the gridview, a custom datepicker widget extension, etc. too, and prefer not to go and extend all the classes. Hence was wondering whether I can handle it in a javascript or css file by editing one or two files.

Comment: Apparently there was no problem to begin with. I just overrode the form-control class in my custom css file, and it took my settings. Next time I should try something first. Nevertheless choosing your answer as it may be helpful to someone who is new to extending classes.